# Shell script to grep more records having a text

Tags: shell, unix, grep, sh, logfile

I want to grep for a message say "Successfully completed" in the log file for the latest activity performed using shell script.The log file is huge and records differ by few seconds only. I am writing those grepped records onto a file.Can someone help me in doing this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have already tried?

Comment: I want to get only the latest done activity record                                       `grep -E "Stage process completed sucessfully" $STAGE_LOG | tail -n500 | tee -a $_TMP_MESSAGE_FILE |`

Comment: It seems like you may already have a solution, what is the question?